# Is it possible to use greater than equal to operator in group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Please suggest me the way to use greater than equal to operator in group by in sql.

Comment: What do you want to do with that?

Comment: What would you hope to achieve by doing that? Are you thinking of using HAVING instead of WHERE?

Comment: You need to give us something more specific to answer.   Possibly read this first?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about using the > operator WITH the GROUP BY clause, then:

```
select
case when age between 0 and 20 then '0 - 20'
     when age between 21 and 40 then '21 - 40'
else '> 40' end age,
sum(case when survived = 1 then else 0 end) survivors
from rms_titanic
group by 
case when age between 0 and 20 then '0 - 20'
     when age between 21 and 40 then '21 - 40'
else '> 40'
order by
case when age between 0 and 20 then '0 - 20'
     when age between 21 and 40 then '21 - 40'
else '> 40';
```

This can be written as:

```
select
case when age between 0 and 20 then '0 - 20'
     when age between 21 and 40 then '21 - 40'
else '> 40' end age,
sum(case when survived = 1 then else 0 end) survivors
from rms_titanic
group by 1
order by 1;
```

However, if you want to use > operator on the result set of the GROUP BY, then you will have to including HAVING clause:

```
select
case when age between 0 and 20 then '0 - 20'
     when age between 21 and 40 then '21 - 40'
else '> 40' end age,
passenger_class,
sum(case when survived = 1 then else 0 end) survivors
from rms_titanic
group by 1, passenger_class having count(*) > 20
order by 1;
```

Comment: Why the -1? I can't believe this.

Comment: No idea, yours is a perfectly reasonable response to an ambiguous question. Levelled you out.

Comment: @RichBenner - Sometimes people don't know what they are asking. Which is fine. Our job is to help. Maybe the guy asking the question is not as articulate as the rest of us. Hence. :)

Comment: Yep, I agree. I can understand the frustration with questions like this however, very vague questions with no explanation of the knowledge level of the questioner and no list of what's been tried before. If questioners are very beginner then this is totally fine, I'd personally point them to training resources rather than giving them the answer straight off the bat. There's no learning in that, which is critical in this line of work.

Comment: Calm down.  I gave a `-1` because the answer at the time was only three lines long, very incomplete and total jibberish.  As you have editted and finished your answer it's no longer jibberish and I'll remove the -1.

Comment: @RichBenner - Agree! I'd keep that in mind.

Comment: @MatBailie - +1 :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree that guessing at an answer to a question this vague should be up-voted.  It is not so much an answer as a guess.

Comment: Each to their own, I do believe that this answer would be perfectly valid given the assumption of what OP means. Could be useful for any visitors from google.

Comment: @MatBailie - Rich has made a good point and so have you. I'll keep your suggestions in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want to do, this is the only thing I can think of:

```
...
GROUP BY 
  CASE WHEN A >= 1 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END
```